# Electron run in production mode

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm using the npm package https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-is-dev

For some reason, `isDev` always returns true.

My npm script looks as follows:

```
"start:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production && electron dist/main.js"
```

main.js:

```
import isDev from 'electron-is-dev';

app.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('isDev', isDev);
  if (!isDev) {
    const {session} = require('electron');
    session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, callback) => {
      callback({responseHeaders: `default-src http: ws:`})
    })
  }
  const win = createWindow();
  createMenu(win);
});
```

The console outputs:

```
isDev true
```

Documentation mentions:

> You can force development mode by setting the ELECTRON_IS_DEV
>   environment variable to 1.

But I don't feel that putting the variable to zero should be necessary.

Outputting `process.env.ELECTRON_IS_DEV` logs undefined.

I found the following thread that I found confusing: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7714

I don't see the use of an extra environment variable, when you set the NODE_ENV on startup... Unless there is a compelling reason not to, I will just check on `process.env.NODE_ENV` as I'm used to.

Comment: By dev tools do you mean the inspection panel in the electron window, or do you mean something else.

Comment: @ameer I don’t see where I mentioned devTools...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't use that npm package but I'll share what I do – (no idea if it is right or wrong but it works. I use it to run `electron-reload` during development).

*package.json* – set an env var in my 'start' script

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "APP_DEV=true electron ."
   }
```

*main.js* - check for the env var in "main.js"

```
var isDev = process.env.APP_DEV ? (process.env.APP_DEV.trim() == "true") : false;
```

use it

```
if (isDev) {
    require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
        electron: upath.toUnix(upath.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '.bin', 'electron'))
    });
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** 4.28.20

Had to bring my project over to a Windows machine to work on some Windows-specific issues and the method above does not work there. Here is my question on that and an answer which gets it working on Windows: [Setting an env var in package.json for use with electron-reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60659194/setting-an-env-var-in-package-json-for-use-with-electron-reload)

Comment: Is there a benefit doing so against just using the default NODE_ENV variable?

Comment: @Trace - honesty, I don't know. I've been doing it this way for a couple of years now and don't remember – I think I encountered some issue with using the default NODE_ENV variable. The method above worked so I moved on to other things.

Comment: Ok thanks @NoGrabbing (lol). Same here. I will use this; if there is a problem sooner or later, or (preferably) never.

Answer (score 2):

You can use electron builtin variable for this that is **app.isPackaged**
It can be  found here https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appispackaged-readonly
Add the below line to check it yourself

```
console.log(app.isPackaged);
```

Else

If you are using Electron-is-dev then use

```
"start": "set ELECTRON_IS_DEV=0 && electron ."
```

Which will set the environment to production.
And for setting it back to DEV replace that 0 with 1.

References - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/manage-staging-environments-in-electronjs/

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that the `process.env` variable in development contains information about npm_package which is absent in production build.
Checking for `process.env.npm_node_execpath` gives me info about prod or dev.