# Setting an env var in package.json for use with electron-reload?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, package.json

I usually develop on macOS but I've moved the project over to Windows 10 in order to work on some Windows-specific issues. I use `electron-reload` to reload the app when changes are made. It's been working wonderfully on macOS but breaks on Windows.

Using the setup below, and `npm start` to start the app, on Windows it throws an error: `"'APP__DEV' is not recognized as an internal or external command"`

Am I doing this wrong and macOS is just more "forgiving"? I saw this question: [Setting process.env var in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624054/setting-process-env-var-in-package-json) and the accepted answer looks the same as what I am doing so I'm confused.

Before I jump down the rabbit hole, I thought I would ask if there is something simple wrong with what I am doing.

If it matters – I didn't do any conversion of CTLF, etc when moving the project to Windows – I just copied it over using `DropBox`.

---

package.json

```
"start": "APP_DEV=true electron .",
```

---

Main.js

```
let isDev = process.env.APP_DEV ? (process.env.APP_DEV.trim() == "true") : false;

if (isDev) {
    require('electron-reload')(__dirname);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `ENV_VAR=value program arguments` is a UNIX thing. Windows does not provide a way to set an environment variable and run a program in the same command, however, this will generally work: `set ENV_VAR=value && program arguments` (so, in your case: `set APP_DEV=true && electron .` is what you're looking for). As a suggestion, look at [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and/or [cross-os](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-os) to make your project more usable (in this regard) on all systems without too much headache.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried moving your argument till after the electron command ("electron") and src location (".")?

APP_DEV does NOT exists:

```
"start": "APP_DEV=true electron ."
```

APP_DEV does exists:

```
"start": "electron . APP_DEV=true"
```

**EDIT:**

The above mentioned method would not be able to retrieve as enviromental variables, but as process arguments. Not sure if this will be able to solve your issue.

```
string[] argument = process.argv;
```